# add and remove options from select box when other item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have used the code (below) which was featured on jsfiddle. The problem i have is that if i change the option value to be different from the text value, it then adds the value back into the text field on change.

```
jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('.selbox').change(function(){
            var val = jQuery(this).val();

            var sel = jQuery(this);

            if(val != "")
            {
            if(sel.data("selected"))
            {   
            var oldval = sel.data("selected");


            sel
           .siblings('select')
           .append(jQuery('<option/>').attr("value", oldval).text(oldval));
           }

           sel
            .data("selected", val)
            .siblings('select')
            .children('option[value=' + val + ']')

            .remove();
          }
          else if(val == "")
          {
          if(sel.data("selected"))
          {   
           var oldval = sel.data("selected");


           sel
           .removeData("selected")
           .siblings('select')
           .append(jQuery('<option/>').attr("value", oldval).text(oldval));
           }
           }            
           });
           });
```

I am using code

```
<option value="1">text here</option>
```

Please see here for the original code http://jsfiddle.net/BUuZv/2/

Comment: I've read your question over and over and I'm not sure as to what you want exactly. If I choose option 1 from the first menu, it will remove option 1 from menu 2 and 3. That is ok right? But if I change option 1 to option 2 again in the first menu, you don't want option 1 to show in the other two?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing them and adding them, you could simply `hide/show` them like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUuZv/17/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.selbox').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var sel = $(this);

        if (val != "") {
            if (sel.data("selected")) {
                var oldval = sel.data("selected");
                sel.siblings('select').find('option[value="' + oldval + '"]').show()
            }

            sel.data("selected", val).siblings('select').children('option[value=' + val + ']').hide();
        }
        else {
            if (sel.data("selected")) {
                var oldval = sel.data("selected");
                sel.removeData("selected").siblings('select').find('option[value="' + oldval + '"]').show()
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to work this out today, here is how I have done it. When the user selects other, it gives a prompt box to add the new option value.

```
 function edit_other(e){ //e just stands for element, it can be any varaible name e is just standard practice after using "this"
    
    
        if(e.value == "Other"){
            //only run function if "other" option has been selected
    
                var proceed = false;
            while(proceed == false){
                prompt_response = prompt("Please enter new material type:"); //Create Prompt box
                if (typeof(prompt_response) == "string"){
    
                             prompt_response = prompt_response.trim(); //tidy end
    
                    if (prompt_response != ""){//// no value provided by the user on "ok button press"
                         proceed = true;
                        //alert('Please Enter a value to continue or press Cancle!');
                    }
    
                }
                if (prompt_response === null){////cancel hits
                    proceed = false; //make sure proceed is still false
                    break;
                }
            }
                //once the user enters a valid value add option script
            if(proceed == true){
    
                    var new_option = document.createElement("option"); //create nre DOM option element
                new_option.text = prompt_response; //Make the text value equal to promt repsonse
                    new_option.value = prompt_response; //Make the option select value equal to promt repsonse
                    new_option.selected = true; //OPTIONAL: select the new added value, most people will select this if they are adding a new value
                    e.add(new_option); //add new option
            }
    
    
        }
    }


   

 <select id="xxx" onchange="edit_other(this)">
       <option value="1"> First Option </option>
       <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <select>
```